# Resolve a virtual path within a Handlebars.java view for Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, handlebars.java

I'm trying to hook up a Handlebars.java as a simple view engine for Spring MVC. I've added a Bean for the `HandlebarsViewResolver` and can get a view to render.

What I'm trying to do now is resolve virtual paths in my views into absolute ones. For example, I have a link to a stylesheet:

```
<link type="stylesheet" src="/style/theme.css" />
```

I need the URL to resolve to an absolute path which takes into account the virtual host path the application may be running under. If the application is requested via `http://test.site.com/dev/` the URL would resolve to `/dev/style/theme.css`. For a given request, I can obtain the base path information easily, but the only thing I can think of doing is adding a `basePath` property to the Handlebars context for every context, and resolve the virtual path by prefix.

```
<link type="stylesheet" src="{{baseUrl}}/style/theme.css" />
```

This would mean either having all my models inherit from a base set of properties, or use a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) to process every model to add in the property.

I've also looked at creating a helper function, but I run into the same problem of having to add to the context for every request, as Spring doesn't seem able to create a `ViewResolver` for each request, with a dependency on the `HttpServletRequest` that I could use in the helper function definition.

I can't help but feel this is a really common scenario, one that's catered for in most view engines. Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

The `HandlerInterceptor` is definitely a good option.

Another option can be a `ControllerAdvice` like:

```
// Target all Controllers annotated with @HandlebarsController
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = HandlebarsController.class)
public class AnnotationAdvice {

    @Autowired
    ConfigServiceImpl configService;

    @ModelAttribute("baseUrl")
    public String getBaseUrl() {
       return configService.findBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

[Spring MVC Controller Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice)